# Is it possible to download graph of scalars in TensorBoard?

Tags: r, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, tensorboard

I'm using Tensorboard to visualize the training of a neural network in R. Tensorboard gives really nice graphs of the accuracy, the loss, validation accuracy etcetera. I would like to download these graphs (including smoothing and legend) just like one can download the graph of the nodes. **Is this possible?** I know that you can download the data one by one, but then you would have to make the graph manually including the smoothing and legend. This would be a lot of work, while you already have such a nice looking graph. I have tried using SVG Crowbar, but I don't know which one to download (if this even works...). I do not know what to do. The best solution thus far seems to be using printscreen and paint.

Thanks in advance for helping me!